# Mute scripts in Chrome's developer tools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

Is it possible to hide all console output from some scripts in Chrome's developer tools? Sometimes third-party libraries or APIs provide some information in console. That's OK, but can be very annoying when you want to debug your own code.

More simply, can I ask developer tools to hide console output from `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` (just dummy example). Or even better, to show only error level for this source?

Yes, there are some ways. I can add a string marker to text which allows me to filter my messages. I can play around overriding `console` instance... I wonder if there is such funtionality built in developer tools?

Comment: You could override the native console with your own console object, and use that instead instead of the original. That way you can capture log calls from other scripts.

Comment: @Teemu, thanks for your suggestion. That's really good when you deal to your codebase and I often use this method. But in some cases you have no possibility to do that for different reasons (not related to development). Especially when you work on part of a big project as outsourcer, you can be a bit restricted to intrude into project's environment.

Answer (score 2):

Accidentally found a part of answer.

If you right-click on any message in console, there is `Filter` item in context menu. And you can hide there messages from exact source.

Still wonder if there is possibility to set logging level per source.