# console.log not working in non-icognito mode in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I have a problem with console.log in regular mode in Google Chrome. The same code logs correctly in Opera and in incognito mode in Chrome.
Here I've read recommendations to turn off Firebug extention but I don't have it.
[Console.log messages not showing up in Chrome's javascript console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240523/console-log-messages-not-showing-up-in-chromes-javascript-console/3241505)

I tried to turn off all extentions and then tested console.log (and alert) again with no success. [in incognito mode it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTHcm.png), also levels filter is set to All levels (why is it disabled btw?) so nothing is hidden.
the same code

```
$("#turnOffAll").click(function(){
    var filterId=$('#filterId').val();
    console.log('clicked on filter'+filterId);
});
```

in regular mode in Chrome outputs nothing.

what can cause this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a filter turned on in the console to only show certain log levels? That's a really common thing a lot of developers accidentally do.

Comment: Possibly relevant (someone that wanted to mute them). Follow the reverse steps if so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737141/mute-scripts-in-chromes-developer-tools-console

Comment: I didn't know that output can be filtered like this, thanks. I checked, there is nothing  hidden too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have enabled a correct level in your console:

[image: Example]

Comment: This dropdown menu is set to All levels and is disabled (see screenshot in post)

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log` directly in the browser console?

Comment: yes it displays 2 rows which are a string passed to console.log and "undefined"

Comment: Really weird, maybe there's a cache file in Chrome that is overwriting your script. Can you delete the cache and try again?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the cache worked for me. Open 3-dot-menu -> more tools -> delete browser data -> select cache.